# How to Customize personalized ubuntu installation including nvidia drivers

Tags: installation, nvidia, kernel, graphics, nouveau

I have a computer with 12 core processors, 32 GB memory and Nvidia GTX 530M graphics card.
I tried to install the gnome-desktop preceded by the server-12.10 installation. It took some attempts to finally graphics work after the kernel update from 3.5 to 3.6.

But now, my desktop stops responding after some time, there are some error messages too. I guessed this is due to improper upgradation of the kernel or some other driver(package).

I want to prepare my own installation cd now from which I can select the mutually compatible packages one by one. Is it possible?

I am really tired of getting my computer working with problems popping up one by one.
Any easy solutions, (I am not very good in commands)

thanks

Comment: "I am not very good in commands" if that is the case... forget about it. You need serious coding skills and need to have detailed knowledge regarding the inner workings of Ubuntu. Plus what you want to do is bound to change per Ubuntu release. Suggestion: if I was you I would make notes and create a post installation script to make the manual work automated. And report anything even smelling like a bug ;)

Answer (score 0):

to select what you want to install one by one during installation
you can try using ubuntu minimal and just select what you want to install
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

then you can follow the instructions here:
http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/2012/02/24
(external link)

if you want to make a customized disc
you can also set up an existing configuration and try remastersys (but check if it works with raring / 13.04)

looks like
remastersys original creator(s) are stopping support but it will be forked.  (binaries have been posted on sourceforge)
search os4systemimage in sourceforge
[i'm not connected to this project]

the newest kernel in 13.04 should suit your set up, but if it still results in bugs for your system you can also try the older kernel (the last one they used in 12.10), as the kernel in 13.04 had a few apparent bugs the last time I used it.  (i.e. getting stuck on logo screen)

it would be interesting to know your processor name. who knows it could help other users or developers / troubleshooters.  I'm betting it's an AMD processor.